# Playstation plus months, how long is that month?

Tags: playstation-plus

I have a 1 month subscription to playstation plus, and playstation plus refreshes every first tuesday of any month. Today is the last sunday of this month.... 
Does the subscription end on tuesday of the next month or will it continue to the last sunday of the next month????

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A month subscription will last exactly 1 month from the activation/purchase day. Depending on how you obtained the PSN Month's subscription it will automatically renew it if you bought it in the store and not activated it trough a code.

One other thing worth mentioning is you won't be able to play the Free games without a PSN subscription. I own Rocket League, but had to stop my subscription for few weeks, and I couldn't play any of the games that I got for free.

TLDR: It lasts for 30 days. If you start it now, you can get this month's games and next month's games and play them till the 25 of May.

Comment: To clarify, any games you **buy** (ie, pay money for) from the Playstation Network, you can play without a Playstation Plus subscription. However, any games you get for free as part of Playstation Plus can only be played while your Playstation Plus subscription is active. That said, if you let it lapse, and reactivate it later, you can play the games you had earlier